# What is the "unit axis"?

Tags: terminology, quaternions

As the highlighted text in the screenshot, what is the unit axis? And what mathematical properties the three coordinates X, Y, Z have?
[image: unit axis]

Comment: Isn’t it the axis on which we want to rotate the object having unit length, like striking a pencil in the object and rotating around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means a vector of length 1.